# Azure Storage access slow only from certain AppService

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm have an Azure AppService which hosts a php webpage. This AppService accesses a blob storage account in order to load data that are then displayed on the webpage.

I use the azure-storage-blob SDK. To initiate the connection to the blob storage I do this:

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
define ("CONN_STRING", "MYCONNECTIONSTRIN");
$blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService(CONN_STRING);
```

This simple operation is extremely fast when executed:

1. on my local PC
2. on a local test server
3. from inside my productive Azure WebService

However when I run this piece of code in the test Azure WebService the response time until I am connected to the blob storage is ~10 times higher.

So far I have found no settings or any differences in the test WebService that could explain the increased latency in the latter case.
The affected WebService is not under any high load.

Again: I am connecting to the identical BlobStorage instance in all cases.

Comment: question: all the app services and storage accounts are in the same azure region? The delay can be a network latency issue

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thanks for taking some time!
Yes, all services and storage accounts are situated in the same region. I am sure this is due to some setting in the slow AppServices. I already checked the Azure documentation as well as the doc of the SDK.

the function BlobRestProxy::createBlobService() calls "StorageServiceSettings::createFromConnectionString" and also invokes the constructor for "BlobRestProxy".
Especially these two calls are pretty slow and take > 200 ms.

Comment: which programming language are you using? There's a chance it's taking some time to get an authorization token

Comment: I am using php.
However the internal call to "$settings->hasSasToken()" in "BlobRestProxy.php" (which is part of the SDK) doesn't seem to be the problem as this function always returns right away.

Comment: you'd better raise an issue on github where engineers can give a better look on what's going on

Comment: I guess you are right. Your attempt to help is highly appreciated though!